# Size of box vs. discrete-ness of state of the system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, boundary-conditions, discrete, regularization

From *Statistical Physics, 2nd Edition* by F. Mandl, pg. 36:

> A sufficiently large box (say 10 light-years across) will clearly not affect the properties of our system, ion plus electron sitting somewhere near the middle. This result is quite general. We can always force a system to have discrete states by enclosing it in a sufficiently large box. In view of this, we shall generally assume that *every macrostate of a system comprises a perfectly definite number of microstates of the system.*

What do they mean when they say "We can always force a system to have discrete states by enclosing it in a sufficiently large box"? How does increasing the size of the box *make* the system's states be discrete? If we instead decrease the size of the box from infinity, at what point is this statement not true? At what size of the box are the states no longer discrete?

Comment: What the author really means is that physicists are happy with pidgin mathematics and they don't want to be bothered with the pesky details of functional analysis and the subtle differences between discrete and continuous operator spectra. He is correct in the sense that it doesn't matter because the physical model breaks down way before the mathematical fudging would rear its ugly head, so you can just go with the flow. If your inner mathematician is unhappy then you are looking at a couple of full time classes in the mathematics department.

Answer (score 6):

The book's sentence "we can always force a system to have discrete states by enclosing it in a sufficiently large box" is perhaps a little unclearly worded.  Putting the system into a box of any size will force the system to have discrete states.  The author's point is that it's always possible to choose a box size that's big enough that the box's existence has no significant physical effect on the system.  That is, considering the system to only have a discrete set of states isn't a physically significant limitation.

Comment: "Putting the system into a box of any size will force the system to have discrete states." - so if there is no box (or container), then the system does not have discrete states? Why?